# What is the Rails way to account the statuses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

When I have only two statuses for an object, like 'active' and 'retired' for employee, I'd have a boolean field in the table users to account the user's status.

But what should I do if I have an object with three or more statuses? A task may be 'new', 'in progress', 'finished' and 'closed', and a computer may be 'ordered', 'in store', 'in use', 'in repair' and finally 'disposed'.

I can see several options:

1) Additional table 'statuses'. Status belongs to task, task have one status. It looks ok for me, but it takes additional table.

2) Somehow have a list of statuses in the 'users' table. Don't know if it's possible. I'm using PostgreSQL.

3) Decide that 1 means 'new', 2 - 'in progress', 3 - 'finished' and use these numbers as stauses.

4) Use name of status as a status. Make the field 'status' a string.

What is the best Rails way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the gems like [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) or [aasm](https://github.com/rubyist/aasm) where I have to create the string column for current state. So I think thats the right way because It gives me the information about the status right away.

Comment: Wow! They look powerful. Thank you!